OpenContainer usage with Page and Router
We'd like to use a OpenContainer style Container Transition included within the library animations within one or more of our (go_router) router based transitions. Unfortunately all I can find seems to be OpenContainer itself, which handles the timing, animating, etc internally and doesn't play nicely with the router's Pages or CustomTransitionPage's transitionsBuilder.
Shy of making a completely custom transition ourselves is there a way I'm missing to use it or something else to do a Container Transition here? Thanks so much for your help!

Consider exploring third-party libraries or packages that provide more flexible router transitions. While these libraries may not directly integrate with OpenContainer, they may offer alternative solutions for achieving similar effects.

You'll likely need to write a middleware layer. OpenContainer is a StatefulWidget and there shouldn't be any reason why you couldn't integrate it with a CustomTransitionPage. I'd start by looking at how a CustomTransitionPage is put together by reading the documentation. Since you said you've already tried doing that, you might need to reverse engineer the OpenContainer animation and implement it yourself, unfortunately.
